# In a GIT bugfix branch, how to pull and then remove another branch (just to test it together)?

Tags: git

I would like to know what is the ideal process in the following scenario :

- develop feature A
- feature A makes apparent a bug (B) from another part of the software.
- create a bugfix branch off A in order to fix B. Without A, we cant see that the bugfix B is effective. (edit: because we can only see the bug when A is there. B has always been wrong, but no visible symptom until the branch A. branch A has nothing wrong in itself)

Now in the PR for the bugfix, there is branch A which make it much harder to see in the diff what the bugfix is. Plus the tech reviewer risks to be tempted to review things from A in the bugfix branch B.

So, branch A in bugfix branch B is good for the feature reviewer but bad for the tech reviewer.

I have been thing of pulling-unpulling A into B as needed, but unpulling does not seems something solid (maybe I'm wrong)

My question here is not only git syntax, but more general workflow to handle such case. I would like to avoid constraining reviewers to do git work, and show thing ready to review.

Do you know a nice workflow in such case ? (please add git commands in you response if it is a bit fancy)

Answer (score 0):

I apologise from the beginning if I'm getting something wrong, but something about your details got me confused, although I read twice or thrice ("Without A, we cant see that the bugfix B is effective" - how can B be without A, when it originated in A?)

Regarding the question in the title:
If you have a branch `X` and what to pull another branch `Y` in it just to test it and then remove it, I suggest cloning branch `X` into a `X1` and then merge the `Y` branch in it, so you can see/test how they behave together. After that, branch `X1` can be safely deleted.

```
git checkout X; 
git checkout -b X1;
git merge Y;
```

This can also be done in a pull request for better visualisation.

However, if you are developing a feature branch `A` as stated in your first bullet there, there is no need for creating a bugfix branch off `A`, until you have merged your branch A into the main branch (`master`, or whatever you called it). Fixing bugs should be done directly into A.

My proposed solution, at least how I enjoyed working on projects so far is:

- create feature branch `A` off `master` branch
- every now and then, to test that everything works ok on `A`, merge the `master` branch into A (`git checkout A; git merge master;`) -> This ensures that the feature branches are always up-to-date with your master branch, and furthermore makes the final PR for the branch more easy, as less changes will exist between the two.
- when finished developing on feature branch `A`, merge it via a pull request

Hope this is helpful in some way

Comment: thanks. I have edited the question to clearup confusion. basically your advice is to have a branch with both bugfix B and "revealing" feature A together, just for review but not merging. This seems good, imo as long as the bugfix is small and there is not many iterations on it.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what state the feature branch is in.

- If the feature branch is merged into master, a hotfix branch is appropriate; create it off of master (via `git checkout -b <good_hotfix_name_here>`), fix the aberrant behavior, verify it **on that branch**, and merge it back into master.
- If the feature branch is not merged into master, no hotfix branch is necessary; fix the bug with the next commit.

This statement is a bit worrisome:

> Without A, we cant see that the bugfix B is effective.

The bug should be reproducible in A, and not reproducible in B.  If you don't have a way to validate this code, you should make this your absolute top priority.

This statement is a *lot* more worrisome:

> Now in the PR for the bugfix, there is branch A which make it much harder to see in the diff what the bugfix is. Plus the reviewer risks to be tempted to review things from A in the bugfix branch B.

This implies two things:

- The code review did not catch this bug, implying that there are deficits in the review process.
- The code was merged before it had a chance to be fully verified, implying that there are deficits in the quality assurance and validation phases.

Your reviewers must be disciplined enough to treat each commit as an atomic instance.  If there's one set of pull requests out there, then don't let them be distracted by any other PR/branch/commit.  If there's a commit that addresses all of the issues brought up by the review, then those fixes *need to be on that branch*.

Comment: I am aware of my poor wording (question edited) that has been misleading for you. Do I understand right that your advice is to have the bugfix in the branch A, but simply in its own commit ?

Answer (score 0):

Find either the A-B merge base or bisect for the commit that introduced the bug. Fix it there and merge it in to both A and B (if there are more affected refs, e.g. release tags for supported versions, include them in your merge-base command0).

```
# if there's more than A and B involved, include them in this command

base=`git merge-base A B`   # the bugged commit is often better but 
                            # there's no easy command to find it :-)

git checkout $base
# fix fix commit commit
git checkout A; git merge $base   # or `git branch fix314 $base` and merge by name
# repeat the above for each branch
```

Some shops have local policies about recorded merges, if they say you can't do that then add `--squash` above.

Comment: I am not sure to understand everything here ("bissect"). The bug is part of a feature that has been introduced months ago, but was never visible until I did feature A. It is in a multi-team organisation, so it is not about my own commit history. I want the fix itself to be reviewed, because there may be stuff produced in-between that rely on the faulty behavior.

Comment: Okay, don't worry about bisect until you're more comfortable with using git as your engineering log.  But there are multiple schools of thought on how that log should look, a big bifurcation about recorded merges, there are many who don't like them because ~they make history nonlinear~, and many shops sharply restrict their use.  Check for local rules and use that to decide whether to specify `--squash` on your merges.  I'll edit in more explanation.